# jQuery automated content via .html(...)

Tags: jquery, html

I have a basic jQuery webpage that shows off some basic features, however there are some not so basic components as well. Some of my portions of the page require SQL queries via external PHP pages. These pages are feed into the main webpage via a GET, then inserted into a div. The code design to perform this action is shown below:

```
function changeSystem(sysName)
{
    pageReq = "menu/"+group+"/"+sysName+".php";
    $("#thesys").load(pageReq);
    stylize();
}
```

Stylize was created into a function to describe my styles (call via the function above and though the page creation):

```
function stylize()
{
    $("#form").submit(function(event) {event.preventDefault();});
    $(".tabs").tabs();
    $("button").button();
    $(".radioset").buttonset();
    $(".sortable").sortable();
    $(".sortable").disableSelection();
    $(".accordion").accordion();
}
```

The response returns some buttons and fields according to the page creation. The code works great, to a point. The content is displayed, however the returned content is not stylized like all the other jQuery objects on the rest of the page. They show up as traditional buttons and fields throwing off the look and feel of the page. If I replace the automated content with static imbedded content, the buttons appear appropriately stylized. Do I need to call a specialized jQuery method to correct the style of this page for this new content?

**EDIT:**

The style that I am referring to is jQuery's theme via http://jqueryui.com/. The bordering style, colors and sizes do not carry over into the generated content. The theme of the buttons seem to resemble the default html theme.

**SECOND EDIT:**

Thank you pilotcam for those great recommendations. I have implemented your second recommendation with great success, however the second one I am still working on. The progress is shown above.

Comment: Why arent you using the jQuery `$.get` or `$.ajax` functions? Sounds like you went the hard way. And when you say the content is unstyled, do you mean without CSS styling, or specific javascript styles you have applied?

Comment: probably posting a sample of the returned response would help.

Comment: @Tejs I now changed it to `$.get`. The code looks lot cleaner with it but the jQuery UI style that I choose for the project still does not carry over to the new content. As for jQuery's UI themes, they are a mixture of CSS and JavaScript for the stylized theme as far as I am concerned.

Comment: It sounds like you simply need to have the dynamic content returned by your server contain a `<script>` block that will set up any styling needed when it is loaded into the container.

Comment: See my third suggestion... your stylize function needs to be run from  a callback otherwise you call it before the ajax call completes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery functions to style your original page, you'll need to do the same with the dynamically loaded content.  For example:

```
$("#myButton").button();
```

You might also consider using the jQuery load() function instead of using XMLHttpRequest directly.  (although that won't help the issue at hand)

```
$("#thesys").load("menu/"+group+"/"+sysName+".php");
```

If you need to do something after the load completes, you can add a callback to your stylize() funciton as follows:

```
$("#thesys").load("menu/"+group+"/"+sysName+".php", stylize);
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I implemented the `$("#thesys").load("page.php");` snippet as shown in the edit and I also included the jQuery styles I used.

Comment: Oh wow. Even on one line. I could ask for a better answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

how do you style the page? if you do it programmatically then this will only style existing elements, if new elements are added afterwards the will be unstyled. So I guess you'll have to call the styling methods on the newly added elements